# How can I output more information to log this error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have taken over a ROR project. Newbie-ish. I am getting this error, but I cannot tell where why or what is causing it.

If you look down at the final rescue it shows where its hitting, but I cannot find a way to stack trace back to what method is getting to many arguments.

ERROR: Being logged via method below

```
uncaught wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0) exception while handling connection: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
```

CODE:

```
begin
    ar = ambRequest.request_amb(
      current_user,
      params[:pickup_address],
      plat,
      plng,
      round_trip,
      dlat,
      dlng,
      params[:dropoff_address],
      type,
      params[:notes],
      md,
      params[:payment_token],
      request.ip,
      params[:notify_phone],
      params[:notify_email],
      params[:special_payment_method],
      false,
      nil,
      params[:estimated_time]
    )
    {'_id' => ar.id.to_s, 'status' => ar.status, 'user_id' => ar.user_id}
  rescue InvalidPaymentToken
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => "Invalid Payment Token", 'user_id' => nil}
  rescue NoPricingData
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => "No Pricing Information", 'user_id' => nil}
  rescue RequestFailed
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => 'FAILED', 'user_id' => ar.user_id}
  rescue PaymentFailure
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => "Credit card error. There may be a problem with our servers.", 'user_id' => nil}
  rescue UnknownPaymentMethod
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => "Unknown Special Payment Method. Valid types are [#{ambRequest::VALID_SPECIAL_PAYMENT_METHODS.join(',')}]", 'user_id' => nil}
  rescue ExclusiveAlreadyUsed
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => 'Exclusive token already used', 'user_id' => ar.user_id}
  rescue => e
    u = User.root_user || current_user
    LogEntry.record(u, "uncaught #{e} exception while handling connection: #{e.message}", LogEntry::ADMIN)
    {'_id' => nil, 'status' => 'FAILED', 'user_id' => current_user.id.to_s}
  end
```

UPDATE =====

Here is the stacktrace. Not sure where the issue lies. Is it the last method call?

```
backtrace
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/sendgrid-ruby-5.3.0/lib/sendgrid/helpers/settings/settings.rb:13:in `initialize'\n
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:148:in `new'\n
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:148:in `block in create'\n
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/threaded/lifecycle.rb:161:in `_creating'\n
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/mongoid-5.0.2/lib/mongoid/persistable/creatable.rb:144:in `create'\n
/app/app/models/settings.rb:17:in `singleton'\n
/app/app/models/settings.rb:23:in `use_kue?'\n
/app/app/models/amb_request.rb:513:in `request_amb'\n/app/lib/api_v1/ambs.rb:197
```

UPDate:

```
class Settings


include Mongoid::Document
  field :use_kue, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :api_url, :type => String
  field :api_key, :type => String
  field :staging_url, :type => String
  field :staging_key, :type => String
  field :are_you_awake_interval_minutes, :type => Integer
  field :are_you_awake_duration_seconds, :type => Integer
  field :online, :type => Boolean, :default => false
  field :online_reason, :type => String
  field :blocked_credit_cards, :type => Array

  def self.singleton
    s = Settings.first
    if s.nil?
      s = Settings.create
    end
    s
  end

  def self.use_kue?
    s = Settings.singleton
    s.use_kue
  end
end
```

Comment: I guess you could include `e.backtrace.join('\n')` which will output the backtrace for the error. Depending on ruby version `e.full_message` (>= 2.5) might be useful instead.

Comment: I am running this (testing) on a remote server. In the above suggestions, where do they get printed out?

Comment: you could add `puts e.backtrace` in the final rescue and the result will be printed out in the console

Comment: Backtrace strongly indicates you should be looking around line 17 in your settings.rb file since that's the last user code prior to hitting gem code.  I have a strong suspicion the email information you're passing in to Mongo is in error, since SendGrid is producing the final exception in its initialize routine.

Comment: You don't need to mark your edits with "Update".  You should structure your question so that it can be read as-is by somebody unfamiliar with any previous edits.  The whole idea is to make a question & answer that will help other developers who come to this with a similar problem later.